# Testing web services in Netbeans

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, netbeans

1.I created web services in netbeans using jboss 7, n i testing by typing the url into the browser and  it came up like this..
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The        document tree is shown below.

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>
No such operation: null (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /UnitConversion11/UnitConversion11null)
</faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So does anybody knows what the problem is because I have no idea.Is there anything about the xml file? and where is the xml fil :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because your SOAP request wasn't correctly formulated.  You normally use this SOAP by posting ugly blobs of XML everywhere.  Your simple GET request probably isn't handled by the application you wrote.

From my hazy memory, there is a field in the request called something like soap:operation that identifies which bit of code will end up processing the request and this is of course missing from the GET request.

You could try testing your app using something like SOAPUI, curl, httprequester (..etc) to send a properly formulated SOAP request via POST or you could adapt your code to properly handle the GET request (possibly identified by having a null soap:operation?)

HTH